# QueryException: duplicate association path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, join, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have a requirement like this:

Requirement 1)

```
select * from BigTable

1) Where BigTable.User.FullName = XYZ
2) Where BigTable.Network.Name = XYZ
```

User and Network are seperate tables linked by FK. There are 2 types of options as above. This is actually used for searching.

Requirement 2)

```
1) Order By BigTable.User.FullName ASC/DESC
2) Order By BigTable.Network.Name ASC/DESC
```

After the search is loaded, it should be ordered by either option based on whatever the user prefers to sort the data with.

I wish to implement a more refined code where I do not have to duplicate many numerous JoinQueryOver codes just to handle with all sorts of scenarios which loads the entity joined being the current entity; therefore I am resorting to using JoinAlias so that I have a standardized implementation through the whole code execution. Note that I do not want to rely on HQL if at all possible.

For some reason though, I can't really relay my logic into NHibernate coding. Refer to below:

```
var Query = session.QueryOver<BigTable>();

User funny = null;

Query.JoinAlias(x => x.User, () => funny).Where(() => funny.Full_Name.IsInsensitiveLike("%" + SearchTextFilter + "%"));

return Query.OrderByAlias(() => funny.Full_Name).Desc
                                .Skip(skip)
                                .Take(take)
                                .List<MasterLicensee>();
```

I am getting this error: [QueryException: duplicate association path: User]

Any idea what did I mistyped or something? :)

**EDIT:**

My idea is to separate them for the many possible scenarios involved.

Meaning eg:

Requirement 1) Search by User's FullName.

Then,

Requirement 2) Sort by Network Name.

Just based on this 2 requirements, we can have the option of:

- Requirement 1) Option 1 Requirement 2) Option 1
- Requirement 1) Option 1 Requirement 2) Option 2 <<< these are the problems
- Requirement 1) Option 2 Requirement 2) Option 1
- Requirement 1) Option 2 Requirement 2) Option 2 <<< these are the problems

which will be tedious and ugly to code with. So my thought is to separate them out into segments.

Mixes with different required joins for example:

```
select * from BigTable Where BigTable.User.FullName = XYZ Order By BigTable.Network.Name ASC/DESC
```

How can I get this into NHibernate Query?? Please assist

Comment: Shouldn't the calls `Query.JoinAlias...` and `.OrderByAlias...` be chained?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your main question, I believe your problem is that because you're not chaining as GertArnold suggests, you are in fact creating the same Alias twice.

The [`JoinAlias` and `OrderByAlias`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-aliases) commands map to the `Criteria` command of `CreateAlias()`, which you means you will be specifiying the same alias twice.  As such, your problem is discussed [here](http://blog.dezfowler.com/2008/06/duplicate-association-path-bug-in.html).

So, try chaining the commands so that you're only specifying the alias once, and see if that fixes the issue.